# The limit of the integral

Tags: integration, limits

We want to prove (simple fact) that

$$\lim\limits_{t\to0^+}\left(\int_0^t g(s,u(s))ds\right)=0.$$

What conditions function $g(s,y)$ has to satisfy for this to be true?

Comment: The only thing this needs is that the integral actually exists for $t$ sufficiently close to $0$. I.e., that $g(s, u(s))$ is an integrable function of $s$ for $s \in (0,\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. The properties of the integral will ensure the limit goes to $0$ no matter how $g$ behaves, as long as it is integrable.

Comment: Thought so, but wanted to be safe. Thank you!